# Why are anonymous users allowed to edit questions?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review

Not really much to say here.  I go to review an edit and then I see it is an anonymous user editing.  Which most of these are crap compared to the others.

Answer (score 4):

Even anonymous users can suggest edits. This is what they see:

[image: improve answer]

Read more about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work).

Comment: It doesn't make sense from an app hierarchy point of view.  Changing something is worse than adding a comment and that isn't allowed anonymously.  I build apps and don't get it.  It makes the reviewers combat spam, without the bots having to log in.

Comment: this is a [network-wide feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work), and has been [discussed before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83457/prevent-suggested-edits-coming-from-anonymous-users)

Comment: Thanks for the link, clears things up a little bit.  I still don't agree that users should have to be such a spam filter.  Also I don't see how you can ban an anonymous user.  I could potentially peg the site using different relays all day right?  I guess this will just be an issue when SE gets spammed bombed using that link.  I can tell you from reviewing at ELU most (80%+) of the anonymous reviews are bad or spam.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: Changing something is worse than adding a comment, but suggested edits don't change anything until they're approved. They're high-work, zero-reward, as opposed to low-risk, low-reward comments.

Comment: @mmyers - I agree.  I just think there is an annoyance factor that is placed on the reviewer.  Also in the link that m0sa gives it says that anonymous users will be banned for 7 days if the spam or whatever.  Anyone in the tech world knows there is no way to control an anonymous user.

Comment: RyeBread: That's the point to reviewing edits. The system allows any one to suggest an edit; those with low rep have to get it approved. Consistent with the rest of the rules about rep.

Comment: SE has always preferred to err on the side of being too welcoming. Like, you don't even have to register *at all* to use the site. We had a user once who got to 3k without registering (and would be at 130k now if he didn't get bored). For the number of visits we get, and for how open the system is, there's rather very little spam or trolling. And I don't know why. (I mean, of course there are spam filters working behind the scenes, what little spam we see is just used to feed them — but no one prevents people from trolling with throwaway accounts, yet only one guy actually does it.)